# How to identify Hot and Cold days using map reduce?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, mapreduce

My data looks like:

```
20130101  12.8   9.6
20130102  10.1   3.8
20130103   7.0  -2.2
20130104  11.8  -3.7
20130105   8.6  -1.1
20130106  10.5   1.9
20130107  13.4  -0.1
20130108  16.2   1.4
20130109  17.8  12.4
20130110  20.0  16.2
20130111  15.4  5.0
```

I want to edentify the dates with maximum temperature greater than 40 (A Hot Day) and minimum temperature lower than 10 (A Cold Day).
For that I run the following code :

```
current_date = None
current_temp = None
for line in data.strip(). split('\n'):
    Mapper_data = ["%s\o%s\o%s" % (line.split('  ')[0], line.split('  ')[1],line.split('  ')[2]) ]
    for line in Mapper_data:
        line = line.strip()
        date, max_temp,min_temp = line.rsplit('\o', 2)
        try:
            max_temp = float(max_temp)
            min_temp = float(min_temp)    
       except ValueError:
            continue
       if current_date == date:
           if max_temp > 40:
                current_temp = 'Hot day'
           if min_temp< 10:
                current_temp = 'Cold day'

      else:
            if current_date:
                print ('%s\t%s' % (current_date, current_temp))
            if max_temp > 40:
               current_temp = 'Hot day' 
            if min_temp< 10:
               current_temp = 'Cold day'
           current_date = date
if current_date == date:
    print ('%s\t%s' % (current_date, current_temp))
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
20130101    Cold day
20130102    Cold day
20130103    Cold day
20130104    Cold day
20130105    Cold day
20130106    Cold day
20130107    Cold day
20130108    Cold day
20130109    Cold day
20130110    Cold day
20130111    Cold day
```

But the result I need to have is:

```
20130101    Cold day
20130102    Cold day
20130103    Cold day
20130104    Cold day
20130105    Cold day
20130106    Cold day
20130107    Cold day
20130108    Cold day
20130111    Cold day
```

Because 20130109 and 20130110 are neither Cold nor Hot days.

Please if you have any idea how can I change my code to get the last result please help.

Comment: `for line in data` isn't doing mapreduce... You get mapreduce data from `sys.stdin` http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/ Anyways... `if current_date` is always True

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is sys.stdin working in Jupyther Notebook, bacause I have tried to use it but it didn't work for me

Comment: Jupyter notebooks don't run MapReduce either... You need to send your code to a Hadoop cluster. At the moment, all youre doing is iterating lines of a file and changing some columns

Comment: yes I know that. If you have any idea how I can modify the code,plz help

Comment: I'm only here for the Hadoop tag, not really the Python one. And I linked you how to run Python as Mapreduce, so I would recommend you start there, not using a Jupyter notebook

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Hadoop compatible Python script, it needs to read from STDIN

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    current_date, max_temp, min_temp = line.split()
    condition = None
    try:
        f_min_temp = float(min_temp)
        f_max_temp = float(max_temp)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if f_max_temp > 40:
        condition = 'Hot day'
    if f_min_temp < 10:
        condition = 'Cold day'

    if condition:
         print ('%s\t%s' % (current_date, condition))
```

Here's an example of **running locally**

```
$ python data.py < data.txt
20130101    Cold day
20130102    Cold day
20130103    Cold day
20130104    Cold day
20130105    Cold day
20130106    Cold day
20130107    Cold day
20130108    Cold day
20130111    Cold day
```

For running in Hadoop, please see [Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html)